# Why older visual studio versions installed on my PC?

Tags: visual-studio

Recently I had disk space issue and checked what is occupying on my disk and I found out that there are older VS version folders on my hard drive although I have never installed them and I cant find them in installed programs either.

VS 14.0 is the only one which I installed but where are VS 11.0 and VS 12.0 coming from. I haven't got any SQL Server installed which installs an express version as well.

How can I remove those folders (Is it safe to delete them simply?) because they aren't within the installed program list?

[image]

Comment: It is normal, not everybody that works on VS was done when it was time to ship VS2015.  Looks like, for one, the Phone team that supports C++ projects were falling behind.  Reflective of the fortunes of Phone.  Don't delete these folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such folders do not really indicate multiple versions of Visual Studio are installed.

A folder named "Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" should be better understood as "Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0 Components". Anything (of course like Visual Studio 2012 itself) uses a little bit of the components, will have to install the dependencies which go to that folder.

For example, if you have Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server Management Studio 2012 installed, then you will have 14.0 and 10.0. The latter uses the 10.0 version of Visual Studio Shell.

In your case, you probably have SQL Server Management Tools 2014 installed, don't you?

Comment: No, I havent installed any SQL server instance. As Dev tool only VS 2015 and Xamarin Studio.